# Error when trying to plot directional field

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I keep getting this error of only a size-1 array when I'm trying to graph this directional field. I thought I fixed it but I still keep getting the same error.

im trying to graph dY/dT = (sint)(cosy)

Here is my code this far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *

T,Y=np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,5,.25), np.arange(-3,3,.25))
dY = cos(Y)
dT = sin(T)
dYdT = dY*dT
U = 1/(1+dYdT**2)**0.5*np.ones(T.shape)
V = 1/(1+dYdT**2)**0.5*dYdT

plt.figure()
plt.title('Direction Field for dydt sin(T)cos(Y)')
Q = plt.quiver(T,Y,U,V)
```

Answer (score 0):

`math.cos()` and `math.sin()` return the cos and sin of a *number*.

Try it for yourself: `sin(0.5)` returns 0.479425538604203, but `sin(np.array([0.5, 0.5])` throws the "only siwe-1 arrays can be converted to python scalars" error.

In your script, `T` and `Y` are arrays of shape 24x20.
Simply use numpy's `cos` and `sin` instead:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *

T,Y=np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,5,.25), np.arange(-3,3,.25))
dY = np.cos(Y)
dT = np.sin(T)
dYdT = dY*dT
U = 1/(1+dYdT**2)**0.5*np.ones(T.shape)
V = 1/(1+dYdT**2)**0.5*dYdT

plt.figure()
plt.title('Direction Field for dydt sin(T)cos(Y)')
Q = plt.quiver(T,Y,U,V)
```

This returns:

[image]